# How to import highcharts-more

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I would like to use the spiderweb chart from highcharts, which requires me to import highcharts-more, but I cannot figure out how to do that. Currently, this is how I've added highcharts to my project, from `app.module.ts`:

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import { HighchartsStatic } from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';

imports: [
    ChartModule
]

providers: [{
    provide: HighchartsStatic,
    useValue: Highcharts
}],
```

When I try to import it like this:

```
import * as HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
```

I get the following error:

```
Module '"c:/pdws-view-v2/node_modules/@types/highcharts/highcharts-more"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Here you can find spiderweb example using angular2-highcharts: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZdFJc2Wul4yOGNoGwX4f?p=preview.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `highcharts-more` npm package is deprecated - there's no need to install it. Just make sure `highcharts` is installed.

## Solution:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import more from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
more(Highcharts);
```

Comment: This solved my issues using arearange series in highcharts-vue.  Thanks!

Comment: Works out of the box without any tricks, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, This worked for me. I am now able to create boxplot.

Answer (score 33):

You don't need to use an external module to use highcharts or any of the extension packages in your Angular app. All you need to do `npm install --save highcharts` and then in your component along with the other imports include:

```
// HIGHCHARTS
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
declare var require: any;
require('highcharts/highcharts-more')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/solid-gauge')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/heatmap')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/treemap')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/funnel')(Highcharts);
let chartHolder;
```

and example usage:

```
ngOnInit() {
  chartHolder = Highcharts.chart('container', newOptions);
}
```

and you can update the chart options:

```
updateChart(newOptions) {
  chartHolder.update(newOptions);
}
```

Comment: _declare var require: any_ That is so horrible - but it worked for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Getting an error in the browser "require is not defined". I am using angular version 13 and TS version 4.6.4

Answer (score -1):

Using [add-highcharts-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts#add-highcharts-modules) and I have updated it to spider chart

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { NgModule, Component }    from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }          from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ChartModule }            from 'angular2-highcharts'; 

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    styles: [`
      chart {
        display: block;
      }
    `],
    template: `<chart [options]="options"></chart>`
})
class AppComponent {
    constructor() { 
        this.options = {

            chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'line'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Budget vs spending',
        x: -80
    },

    pane: {
        size: window.innerWidth * .80
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Development', 'Customer Support',
                'Information Technology', 'Administration'],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        lineWidth: 0
    },

    yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 70,
        layout: 'vertical'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Allocated Budget',
        data: [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }, {
        name: 'Actual Spending',
        data: [50000, 39000, 42000, 31000, 26000, 14000],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }]



         };
    };
    options: Object;
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    ChartModule.forRoot(
      require('highcharts'),
      require('highcharts/modules/exporting'),
      require('highcharts/highcharts-more'),
    )
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap:    [AppComponent]
})
class AppModule { }


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

[Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/pbl9FMvBbQjD0M3byNdy/)