# TreeMap chart of Highcharts in Angular

Tags: angular5, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I'm running into issues and not been able to render TreeMap chart. Other chart types like Line works fine in my App. The error I get is Error# 17.
I'm using Angular 5. Can you please share any working sample using Angular5 and Highcharts for TreeMap.

Appreciate your quick help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check official [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts#typescript)

Import like this

```
import * as  Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import More from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
import Tree from 'highcharts/modules/treemap';
import Heatmap from 'highcharts/modules/heatmap';
More(Highcharts);
Tree(Highcharts);
Heatmap(Highcharts);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-highcharts-treemap?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.ts) demo

Comment: Hey, this seems to be ionic app and not angular app.

Comment: this doesnt seem to work. I get many errors when I try to use your sample in angular5

Comment: remember in am not using angular2-highcharts but using official highcharts npm package. Do check

Comment: It gives me error for this imports: `code` import  More from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
More(Highcharts);
import  Tree from 'highcharts/modules/treemap';
Tree(Highcharts);
import  Heatmap from 'highcharts/modules/heatmap';
Heatmap(Highcharts); `code`

Comment: match dependencies of stackblitz demo to your project

Comment: The line where you specified the layoutAlgorithm, I get error on that line as layoutAlgorithm does not exists in type IndividualSeriesOptions

Comment: Finally it worked for me. The import you outlined was not working. I added it like below and that solved my problem: `code`declare var require: any;
require('highcharts/highcharts-more')(Highcharts); `code`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116730/how-to-import-highcharts-more